# Cannot understand the first argument of write()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, io

I came across the statement:

```
outbal.write( (char*) &acc , sizeof( struct status ) );
```

`outbal` is an object of `ofstream` and `status` is a type.

Therefore:

```
struct status {
  // code
};

status acc;
```

Talking about the second line I don't understand the first argument, which is `(char*) &acc`. What are we doing and how?

Comment: Sounds like what you don't understand is casts in general rather than this argument in particular: consult that section of your C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(char*)&acc` if the address of the variable `acc`, cast to a char pointer so as to be compatible with [`ostream::write()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/). It is that variable that is being written, to the `outbal` stream, for a length of `sizeof(struct status)`.

`ostream::write` takes a memory address and a length and will output that memory to the specified stream. In other words, you're simply outputting the entire memory contents of the `acc` variable.

Your code is similar to:

```
struct xyz {int a; float b; void *c};

ostream os("myfile.dat");

struct xyz abc; // 'struct' not technically needed in C++

os.write (  (char *)abc,      sizeof (struct xyz));
//        <<-memory addr->>   <<-----size----->>
```

Comment: what does the cast **`(char*)`** indicate ?

Comment: @grassPro, it casts your structure address to a type suitable for `write`.

Comment: so you dont need to do **`(char*)&abc`** ? _(the ampersand sign)_

Comment: The `&` is required, otherwise it would cast the contents of the structure itself to a pointer.

Comment: You don't need all this `struct` repetition in C++.

Comment: I'm aware of that, @Tomalak, but I _still_ write a lot of code for both C and C++. Saves me having to ifdef all over the place. In any case, I usually typedef it anyway.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That's fine, but I wanted to point it out for the OP, who is writing a C++ program.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the address of `acc` and casting it to `char*`, which is what the `ostream::write` member function expects.

In short, you are writing the in-memory representation of the struct as-is to a stream.

Comment: what does the cast **`(char*)`** indicate ?

Comment: It means reinterpret the address of the struct (of type `status*`) as a pointer to char*. Nothing actually happens at the machine-code level. It just just tells the compiler to treat one type of pointer as another type of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`(char*) &acc` takes the address of the struct `acc` (i.e. a pointer to `acc`) and then casts it into a pointer to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

That's just taking the address of `acc` and casting it to a pointer to `char`.

Most likely that `.write()` method is meant to just blindly write a given amount of bytes out as-is. `char` is a convienent type to use for that, since (on most platforms) it is exactly one byte in size. So you pass it a pointer to the data you want written out, telling it, "Pretend this is a pointer to `char`".